# how to save selected value from drop down list to mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, select, dropdownbox

```
<?php 

  $status=&$_POST['status'];
  $from=&$_POST['date_from'];
  $to=&$_POST['date_to'];
  $conn=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','punbus') or die("Database not connected".mysqli_error());

  if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
    $ins="insert into driver_status(driver_name,status,date_from,date_to)                    
          select Driver_name,'$status','$from','$to' from driver_master";    
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$ins)){
      echo "added";
    }
    else{
      echo "NOT".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
  }

  $sel='select Driver_name from driver_master';
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sel);

  echo "<form action='driver_status.php' method='post'>";
  echo "<table cellpadding=5>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th>Driver Name</th>";
  echo "<th>Status</th>";
  echo "<th>From</th>";
  echo "<th>To</th>";
  echo "</tr>";

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['Driver_name']."</td>";
    $sel1='select d_status from status';
    $query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sel1);
?>

  <td>
    <select name="status">
      <?php
        while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){  
          $st=$row1['d_status'];
          echo "<option value='$st'>$st</option>";
        }
      ?>
    </select>
  </td>
  <?php
    echo "</tr>"; 

  }

  echo "</table>";
  echo '<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Update"/>';
  echo "</form>";
?>
```

That is my code. I want to save option selected from 4 drop down list to   mysql. When I submit the form, the value selected from last box are getting saved in all rows of mysql table. Now, please tell me what should I do?
I am getting drop down box values from database table properly so what is the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is your code.

```
<?php
$status = $_POST['status'];
$driver_name= $_POST['driver_name'];
$from = $_POST['date_from'];
$to = $_POST['date_to'];
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'punbus') or
        die("Database not connected" . mysqli_error());
if(isset($_POST['sub'])) {
    foreach($status as $k=>$s){
        $ins = "insert into driver_status(driver_name,status,date_from,date_to) VALUES                   
            ('".$driver_name[$k]."','$s','$from','$to')";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $ins)) {
            echo "added";
        } else {
            echo "NOT" . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
    }
}

$sel = 'select Driver_name from driver_master';
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sel);

echo "<form action='driver_status.php' method='post'>";
echo "<table cellpadding=5>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Driver Name</th>";
echo "<th>Status</th>";
echo "<th>From</th>";
echo "<th>To</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){    
     echo "<tr><td>".$row['Driver_name']
           ."<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"driver_name[]\" value=\"".$row['Driver_name']."\"/></td>";
     $sel1='select d_status from status';
     $query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sel1);
     echo "<td><select name=\"status[]\">";
     while($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
           echo "<option value=\"".$row1['d_status']."\">".$row1['d_status']."</option>";
     }
     echo "</select></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo '<input type="submit" name="sub" value="Update"/>';
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Comment: it is also not working. is status_$numb is right in select tag?

Comment: `status_$numb` is not tag, it's value of select name attribute.. its will give name `select_1, select_2, select_3, select_4` in your selects. and in your php, you can access that values with `$_POST['select_1'] ..etc`. so your 4 selects not have same names, but different names.

Comment: plz help me on this topic.

Comment: how to use foreach loop if i want to use one more input type text in another <td>.

Comment: just add like as `<input type=hidden>` and placed into <td> tag. in your insert query, you can access like `driver_name` post.

Comment: this time i dont have to get data from database but  i have to add date by selecting from jquery datepicker.

Comment: i can save drop down values to database using foreach loop but now i have to save date with each drop down box. Problem is same the date selected from last datepicker is getting stored to all date field in database.

Comment: names of date input should be array. like as driver_name input.

Answer (score -1):

this is similar to other textbox
    $op="select * from client where active=0";
                               $op1=mysql_query($op);

```
                   echo '<select name="c"  id="c" style="width:160px;"  required>';

                         while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($op1))
                        {
                       echo  $s=$row["c_name"]; 
                          if($company!=$s)
                          {
                          echo '<option  value="'.$row["c_name"].'">'.$row["c_name"].'</option>';
                          }

                        }

            $c=$_REQUEST['c'];
             $sql="insert into project c_name) values('$c')";
   $sql1=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: do you have four select box in your form?

Comment: thanks for posting this code but it is not helping me.